# Thinking in angularJS with a javascript background

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, module, controller

I have worked with javascript before but now I'm getting into angularjs but I am confused about how to do basic stuff.

For example:
In Javascript:

```
 //here is how i create a constructor
   function createUser(name, age, address)
   {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
      this.address = address;

      this.sayName = function()
      {
        return this.name;
      }
   };
```

NOTE: the data to the constructor is being provided by user input through a form.

But in AngularJS I would create a module with a controller in it. And the controller will get user input by using the "ng-model" to bind data and $scope to transfer data to the controller. My question is that, do I create the constructor the same way within my angular module as I did in pure javascript and if yes then how do I create (an example would be great). I want to keep my angular module and controller thin and no too much in it.

An example would be very help. And any advice on how to think in angularjs would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cool thing about angular.js is that it allows you to bind POJO on the scope.

You can create it as you already know and just put it on the scope.

I tend to register constructor functions as services, inject them into a controller and then instantiate an object per use.

For example here is the service:

```
app.factory('User', function() {

  function User(name, age, address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.address = address;
  }

  User.prototype.sayName = function() {
    return this.name;
  };

  return User;
});
```

And a controller:

```
app.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', 'User', function($scope, User) {
  $scope.user = new User('ilan', 30, 'Nahariya');
}]);
```

And a template:

```
<div ng-controller="UserCtrl">
  <h1>{{ user.sayName() }}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: ahhh that makes sense thank you for the answer. One question though are services the only way to put a constructor into the scope? Also do the controller and the service go in the same js file or can I put them into separate files? Again thank you for replying.

Comment: It's not the only way, but DI is the proffered way of doing modular and testable programming. you can and probably should divide your code into separate thin modular files. For the most of all you can use a build tool (gulp) to concatenate and minify your js application.

Answer (score 0):

angular is very good client side javascript framework.

you can register a constructor function for your service object using the
“service(name, constructor)” method:

```
(function() {
  var MyService = function(magicNumber) { // "magicNumber" is injected
    this.getMagicNumber = function() {
      return magicNumber;
    };
  };

  app.service('magicNumberService', MyService);
}());


(function() {
  var MyService = function(magicNumber) { // "magicNumber" is injected
    this.getMagicNumber = function() {
      return magicNumber;
    };
  };

  app.service('magicNumberService', MyService);
}());
```